# Passing collection to email view using laravel 5.3 Notifications

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.3

I have created a notification class to send clients an order confirmation email. In this I would like to add the details from their order which is a collection from eloquent. I have the data in the notifications class. (If I dd($this->order) I get the expected result.)

My Problem is passing the data from the class to the email blade template. I have read through the docs but nothing stands to me out that I can use to pass the whole collection and then to be able to format it in the view.

This is my `OrderConfimation` class

```
class OrderConfirmation extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public $order;
    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user , $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Order Confirmation ['.$this->order->ID.']')
            ->greeting('Hi '.$this->user->F_NAME)
            ->line('Thank you for ordering from Awesome Store.')
            ->line('Once Payment has been confirmed we will send you a Payment Confirmation Email')
            ->line('As your order progresses we will send you updates. You can also track your order status by viewing it on our site at anytime')
            ->action('View Order', 'order url here')
            ->line('Thank you for shopping with us!');
           /**** What do i use here to pass $this->order to the view ????****/

    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
```

I feel the answer will be so easy because it's laravel, I'm just missing it

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using a `Notification` class to send emails. Why not create a `Mailable` class? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail#writing-mailables

Comment: It just made sense to me after reading about notifications. I'm still very new to laravel so I was not aware that I could use the `Mailable`. Have I maybe misunderstood the use of notifications then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use mailable. Here's a basic sample.

first on cmd write

```
php artisan make:mail Notify
```

than make ***order.blade.php*** in a ***emails*** folder it'll be a simple html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Notification</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
Your order #{{$order['id']}}
</p>    
</body>
</html>
```

open ***notify*** in ***App\Mail***

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class Notify extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $order;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($order)
    {
        // to put order data from controller to mailable 
        $this->order=$order;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $address = 'site@info.com';
        $name = 'site.com';
        $subject = 'notification';
        return $this->view('emails.order')->from($address, $name)
        ->subject($subject)
        ->with(['order'=>$this->order]);
        //emails its a folder
        //order its a order.blade.php file
    }
}
```

in any controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Mail\Notify;//load notify mailable
use Mail;// use mail class
class Demo extends Controller
{
    //
    public function save(Request $post){
        $order=array('id'=>'1','desc'=>'lorem ipsum dolore');
        Mail::to("some@mail.com")->send(new Notify($order));
    }
}
```

[check mailtrap incoming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESaup.png)

Comment: This is what I have done. kinda hacked it about using the blade template from notifications but it works so all my mails look and feel the same.